# MVC Ajax POST does not bind subobject

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a controller

```
 [HttpPost]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Report([FromBody][FromForm] ReportViewModel request)
 {
       var x = request.StartDate; // binds data
       var y = request.Pager.RowsPerPage; // always NULL
}
```

The ReportViewModel is

```
public class ReportViewModel : IEntity, IResponse
{
        public string DateRange { get; set; }
        public Pager Pager { get; set; }
}

public class Pager
{
        public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
}
```

I am calling the Controller using AJAX, this is what i am sending from UI

```
{"Pager.RowsPerPage":"1","Pager.CurrentPage":"2","StartDate":"2021-11-08T17:25:21.243Z"}
```

I've tried to create the Pager object on ReportViewModel constructor but no luck.

What can be the issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like this

```
<button id="submitForm">Submit</button>

@section scripts {

<script type="text/javascript">

    var formData = '{ "DateRange": "2021/11/08", "Pager": { "CurrentPage": 2 } }';

    var options = {
        url: '/Home/Report',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.parse(formData)
    }

    $('#submitForm').click(function () {

        $.ajax(options)
        .done(function (response) {
            console.log('response: ', response);
        });
    });

</script>

}
```

and then in the controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Report(ReportViewModel report)
    {

        var dateRange = report.DateRange;
        var page = report.Pager.CurrentPage;

        return Json("{ submited = true }", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }


    public class ReportViewModel
    {
        public string DateRange { get; set; }
        public Pager Pager { get; set; }
    }

    public class Pager
    {
        public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Using this method does not bind even the main object properties. Thanks.

Comment: there you go, i created a small example and tested code its running all good.

Comment: @sairfan I have a very similar problem. Any help would be appreciated. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69906047/serializing-form-subgroups-for-ajax-submission-to-asp-net-mvc