# Serializing Form Subgroups for Ajax Submission to ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, forms

I am creating an application where a note can be created and one to many parts can be added to the note (the application is for a tractor salvage yard where customers call for tractor parts).

I am using Jquery AJAX to load a popup modal with the create view. I am creating a note with its parts in one create view. My problem is I don't see a way to serialize the form data from the create view so that the controller post action can update both classes. Everything previously worked when I had a separate page and url for the create view. I included a screenshot of the create view.

[image: Create View]

Here are my model classes:

```
public class Note
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerPhone { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string AssignedTo { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Part> Parts { get; set; }
}

public class Part
{
     public int PartID { get; set; }
     public string PartNumber { get; set; }
     public string Description { get; set; }
     public int NoteID { get; set; }
     public virtual Note Note { get; set; }
}
```

My post method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Note note)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Notes.Add(note);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(new { success = true });
        }           

        return PartialView("CreateDialog", note);
}
```

I need the `note` parameter to contain the data from the view. When I had a separate page for the create view, it was correctly passing all of the form data including the `Parts` to the `note` parameter when submitted.

This first one shows how the Parts property should be populated with however many parts added in the create view:

[image: Correct Data]

But when I try to use jQuery to serialize and submit this via ajax, I only get this. Even though the Parts input field was populated:

[image: Missing Part Data]

And finally here is my view and javascript. Please explain to me how I can either modify the html so `serialize` will also get the parts or maybe an alternative to `serialize` that I can manually attach the data to each property.

```
<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Note</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerPhone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerPhone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerPhone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateCreated, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateCreated, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateCreated, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateUpdated, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateUpdated, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateUpdated, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreatedBy, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreatedBy, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreatedBy, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AssignedTo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AssignedTo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AssignedTo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


@*I am using js so the user can add part editors to this list. I have a part editor template (below) that this uses.*@ 
        <div class="parts-container create">         
             @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Parts[p])            
        </div>

        <div id="btnWrapper">
            <input id="btnAddPart" type="button" value="Add Part" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Part Editor Template

```
@model CallNote.Models.Part
<div id="part-template" class="part-info">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PartNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "part-number" } })
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "description" } })
    <input type="button" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default delete-button" />
    <br />
</div>
```

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $(".create-button").click(function () {
        $(".ajax-content").load("/note/create", function (e) {
            $(".modal").modal({
                keyboard: true
            }, "show");
            bindForm(this);
        });
    });

    function bindForm(dialog) {
        $("form", dialog).submit(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                complete: function (xhr, status) {
                    if (status == "success") {
                        $(".modal").modal("hide");
                        location.reload();
                    } else {
                        alert("Failed: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    }
```

Comment: rather than using `form.serialize()` pass a js object like `data: { name: '" + $('#name').val() + "', age: "  + $('#age').val() + " }`

Comment: I would also strongly recommend to use some js library or framework like knockout

Comment: @sairfan I realize I can do that. But my question is how I do that with a subobject. Would it be something like this `data: { name: '" + $('#name').val() + "', age: "  + $('#age').val() + ", Parts: { partnumber: '" + $('#part-number').val() + "', and so on for other part properties } }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem in your scenario is that when you use MVC HTML Helper for rendering a Navigation property like to input object it will render like this (if i remember it correctly)

```
<input type="text" name="Parts_PartNumber" value="part abc" />
```

its not going to serialize in a way that MVC controller will understand to bind it with model, for that you need

```
<input type="text" name="Parts[0].PartNumber" value="part abc" />
<input type="text" name="Parts[1].PartNumber" value="part xyz" />
```

what you can do when you dynamically create new input control for part number you also set its name attribute like name='Parts[0].PartNumber'
Here is working example

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public IList<Part> Parts { get; set; }
}

public class Part
{
    public string PartName { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Customer(CustomerViewModel customer)
{

    return Json(customer, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

View

```
<form action="/Home/Customer" method="POST">

    <input name="CustomerName" value="abc" /> <br />
    <input name="Parts[0].PartName" value="xyz" />

    <button id="submitForm" type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>



@section scripts {

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $('form').submit(function () {

        console.log('click', this);


        var options = {
            url: '/Home/Customer',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $(this).serialize()
        }


        $.ajax(options)
        .done(function (response) {
            console.log('response: ', response);
        });

        return false;
    });


    </script>
```

Or an other approach could be js object as we discussed in comments in that case it should look like this

```
data: { customerName: 'name', parts: [ {partName: 'part 1'},  {partName: 'part 2'}]}
```

you can also loop through input objects in html and create json or convert serialized form into a valid json.

Please note that it could be not an ideal approach but this is how I can help you solving the issue.

Comment: The example is exactly what I was looking for. I already had some js naming the parts like you said, but I think the js wasn't working when I was testing.