# passing JSON formatted data with ajax is not working

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-core

I am trying to call an action in my controller with some JSON data, it seems to be reaching the action but the data is all null.

This is what my Ajax function looks like:

```js
function AjaxPost(url, data) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        //I tried adding the following but to no avail:
        processData: true,
        traditional: true,
        success: function (response) {
            //success code
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    });
}
```

This is how I make the AjaxPost function:

```html
<a href="javascript:AjaxPost('./Chat/PrivateChat', {id:123, username:'username', connectionID:'connectionID'})">
```

This is the controller I am calling:

```cs
public IActionResult PrivateChat(int id, string username, string connectionID)
{
    //at this point
    //id = 0
    //username = null
    //connectionID = null
}
```

I have also tried methods from the following sources, but the data stays null:

[link1](https://www.educba.com/jquery-ajax-send-json/)

[link2](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc-how-to-use-ajax-with-json-parameters/)

[link3](https://www.aspsnippets.com/questions/212022/Pass-Send-Json-string-to-Controller-using-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASPNet-MVC/)

Comment: Check the request in devtools - is the data actually empty when you send the request, or is it a problem within the model binding on the server side?

Comment: Also, never use `href="javascript:..."`. Bind an event handler properly by using [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). I'd also suggest removing `traditional: true`. You don't need it here, and it will likely cause more problems that it solves.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The problem is with the model binding, when I console log my data right before the Ajax request it seems fine, but once we pass the Ajax request my data is gone. also I know using href javascript isn't ideal but I have more than one anchor all of them call the same method

Comment: Using console.log isn't the same. You need to check the network tab of devtools after you make the AJAX request to see what it contains. However, assuming the problem is the model binder, then you need to show more of your C# code to debug the issue. The JS wouldn't be relevant to the problem.

Comment: Where you are calling the function, in parameter i dont think its valid json there.

Comment: This example explains what you need [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69906047/serializing-form-subgroups-for-ajax-submission-to-asp-net-mvc/69981577#69981577)

Comment: No, you are certainly missing the `[FormBody]` attribute on your controller signature. Try that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to call an action in my controller with some JSON data, it
> seems to be reaching the action but the data is all null.

Well, based on your scenario and description, you would get null data always. Beause the way, you are sending Json data either you have to have Request model in controller wrapped with [FromBody] or you should post data as query parameter like this way:`"http://localhost:5094/AjaxPostNull/PrivateChat2?id=" + data.id + "&username=" + data.username + "&connectionID=" + data.connectionID`

Let's have a look at practice, how we could achieve that:

Way: FormBody wrapper:

Request Model:

```
public class AjaxRequestModel
 {
     public  int id { get; set; }
     public string username { get; set; }
     public string connectionID { get; set; }
 }
```

Controller Signature:

```
public IActionResult PrivateChat([FromBody] AjaxRequestModel ajaxRequestModel)
{
    //at this point
    //id = 0
    //username = null
    //connectionID = null

    return null;
}
```

**Note:** If you send request along with json model, you should wrapped the controller with [[FromBody]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#sources)

Script:

```
@section scripts {
    <script>
        function PostAjaxRequest() {
            var url = "http://localhost:5094/AjaxPostNull/PrivateChat2?id=" + data.id + "&username=" + data.username + "&connectionID=" + username +;
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                // data: JSON.stringify(data),
                success: function (response) {
                    //success code
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

Alternative way: Query String

[image]

```
@section scripts {
    <script>
        function PostAjaxRequest() {
            

            var data = { id: 123, username: "Test User Name", connectionID: "My con ID" };


            var url = "http://localhost:5094/AjaxPostNull/PrivateChat2?id=" + data.id + "&username=" + data.username + "&connectionID=" + data.connectionID
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                // data: JSON.stringify(data),
                success: function (response) {
                    //success code
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

**Note:** You can also pass the parameters using comma seperated value through the `data:`

Output:

[image]

**Note:** Please [refer to this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#sources) if you want to know more.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `dataType: 'json'`. It will work. Thanks.!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).